# How to Import product using CSV?

Tags: magento-1.9, import, csv

I am facing Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Image does not exist.'

```
<pre>
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
include_once "app/Mage.php";
include_once "downloader/Maged/Controller.php";

Mage::init();

$app = Mage::app('default');

//The category names should be exactly the same name from the csv file where the id is the corresponding category id in magento. This is done when the csv file doesn't contain ids for categories but the name of categories.
$categories = array(
    'Category 1' => 3,
    'Category 2' => 4,
    'Category 3' =>5,
    'Category 4'=>6,


);
$row = 0;

if (($handle = fopen("trem2.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        echo 'Importing product: '.$data[0].'<br />';
        foreach($data as $d)
        {
            echo $d.'<br />';
        }
        $num = count($data);
        //echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;

        if($row == 1){ continue;}

           $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

        $product->setSku($data[0]);
        $product->setName($data[3]);
        $product->setDescription($data[6]);
        $product->setShortDescription('');
        $product->setManufacturer($data[20]);
        $product->setPrice($data[9]);
        $product->setTypeId('simple');


        $fullpath = 'media/catalog/product/thumb/';
        $ch = curl_init ($data[14]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
        $rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
       echo  $fullpath = $fullpath.$data[2].'.jpg';
        if(file_exists($fullpath)) {
            unlink($fullpath);
        }
        $fp = fopen($fullpath,'x');
        fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
        fclose($fp);
       $product->addImageToMediaGallery($fullpath, 'thumbnail', false);

        $fullpath = 'media/catalog/product/small/';
        $ch = curl_init ($data[2]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
        $rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        $fullpath = $fullpath.$data[2].'.jpg';
        if(file_exists($fullpath)) {
            unlink($fullpath);
        }
        $fp = fopen($fullpath,'x');
        fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
        fclose($fp);
       $product->addImageToMediaGallery($fullpath, 'small-image', false);

        $fullpath = 'media/catalog/product/high/';
        $ch = curl_init ($data[2]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
        $rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        echo $data[2];
        echo $fullpath = $fullpath.$data[2].'.jpg';
        if(file_exists($fullpath)) {
            unlink($fullpath);
        }
        $fp = fopen($fullpath,'x');
        fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
        fclose($fp);
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($fullpath, 'image', false);



        $product->setAttributeSetId(4); // need to look this up
        $product->setCategoryIds(array($categories[$data[11]])); // need to look these up
        $product->setWeight(0);
        $product->setTaxClassId(2); // taxable goods
        $product->setVisibility(4); // catalog, search
        $product->setStatus(1); // enabled

        // assign product to the default website
        $product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));

     $product->save();      

$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
            $stockItem->assignProduct($product);
            $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
            $stockItem->setData('stock_id', 1);
            $stockItem->setData('store_id', 1);
            $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
            $stockItem->setData('use_config_manage_stock', 0);
            $stockItem->setData('min_sale_qty', 1);
            $stockItem->setData('use_config_min_sale_qty', 0);
            $stockItem->setData('max_sale_qty', 1000);
            $stockItem->setData('use_config_max_sale_qty', 0);
            $stockItem->setData('qty', $data[4]);
            $stockItem->save();




        $product->save();    


    }
    fclose($handle);

}


?>
</pre>
```

Or what is the  other way to import?

Thanks.!

Comment: what issue .. yum have facing

Comment: @AmitBera he is getting : `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Image does not exist.'`

Comment: @AmitBera I am facing Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Image does not exist.' while import products programmatically using the above code...

Comment: if nothing worked for you, you can go with `magmi`

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand why you use there `unlink` , it will delete your image and thats why you get image not find error

```
    $fullpath = 'media/catalog/product/thumb/';
    $ch = curl_init ($data[14]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
   echo  $fullpath = $fullpath.$data[2].'.jpg';
    /*if(file_exists($fullpath)) {
        unlink($fullpath);
    }*/ //comment this code and check 
    $fp = fopen($fullpath,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks , now the image file uploaded but uploaded image got 0 bytes.